# A bad URL is being served when users search for my app

Tags: facebook, search

As an administrator, when I search for "Care2" in the search bar, I am able to
get to the page (the URL looks like:
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=83187307959).... However if
anyone else tries to search for "Care2" in the search bar, they see the app,
but it takes them to the following URL which then redirects to the 404 page:
http://apps.facebook.com/83187307959/?ref=ts. When I switch that
apps.facebook.com to www.facebook.com, it works fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a logged error that has been going on since Friday (happening for me too):

[new tool](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/204664672932552?browse=search_4e73d1474dee33373887551)

[old tool](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20469)

Comment: They just announced a new bug tool today so I re-added it to the new site.